# Windows 98 hangs after entering password on fresh install

Tags: windows-98

I am doing a fresh reinstall of Windows 98 SE on a Dell Optiplex GX1 550Mbr+.  I previously had this very same version of Windows on this machine.  The install works perfectly, but when I get to the login screen, I hit escape (or type in the password and press enter), and it just hangs.

I have tried:

1. Changing hard drives
2. Changing CD drives
3. Changing the RAM
4. Swapping the hard drive into another machine
5. Removing the password

The first 3 points result in no improvement, event if I re-install from scratch.

When I swap the hard drive into another computer, I can log in just fine, so it doesn't seem to be the installation at fault.

When I remove the password (using another computer), it just hangs at the green desktop background.  The mouse will move, but nothing ever loads.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd> will bring up the task manager, and I can restart the computer, or kill the only process (Hidserv).

Running the computer in Safe Mode works.

Comment: Does the computer have a network card and is it connected? The next thing after login is connecting to the network.

Comment: It has onboard ethernet, but it is not connected.

Comment: Can you try connecting it? Or disable the NIC from safe mode?

Comment: I connected it to the offline network, to no avail.  The online network does not work any better.  I'm going to try disabling it from safe mode now

Comment: Disabling the NIC (I did it right from the BIOS) does not work either - it still hangs right after where the login screen would be (I currently have it removed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer!  Using Safe Mode, in msconf, I disabled all the options in the startup tab except:

- Scan registry
- Task Monitor
- System Tray

That worked, so then I re-enabled the following:

- Load power profile
- Load Power Profile
- Scheduling Agent  `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\mstask.exe`

That was still working, so I restarted again after enabling

- Welcome
- Hidserv

Since that did work, I finally enabled the last option in msconfig:

- Scheduling agent `mstinit.exe /firstlogon`

And it worked!

I tried again on another fresh install on the same computer.  This time, I **only** disabled `hidserv`, and I got the same success (Windows started normally, and I was able to re-enable `hidserv` in msconfig).  So the problem was `hidserv`.